# What is the syntax for IF/ELSE in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to pull logs and doing few others things directly. written a small line BASH but not working. I am sure thats with IF Condition.

```
sed -rne '/21:25:07/,/21:50:07/ p'  server.log.2015-04-21 > /tmp/filename.log ;
du -sh  /tmp/filename.log ; 
if [`du -sh  /tmp/filename.log` -gt 0] then gzip /tmp/filename.log ;
```

Comment: Also in your `sed` command you don't need `-r` and `-e`....also if you have any line containing `21:50:07` before your desired one, this will give you wrong output..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed couple of points, the correct (**Only syntatically**) form would be:

```
if [ `du -sh  /tmp/filename.log` -gt 0 ]; then gzip /tmp/filename.log; fi
```

- There must be space after `test` (`[`) and before `]`
- You need to put a `;` (synonymous to newline) after first `if` condition
- You need to close the `if` condition using `fi` at last portion

Also you should use `$()` instead of  `` as command substitution as the latter one is deprecated in favor of `$()`.

So, literally you command can be made more robust:

```
if [ $(du -sh  /tmp/filename.log) -gt 0 ]; then gzip /tmp/filename.log; fi
```

**Most importantly**, there is another major problem in your `if` condition, you are comparing a string (output of `du -sh  /tmp/filename.log`) with an integer (`0`), which is wrong.

You can do the following:

```
if [ $(du -s ./test.txt | cut -f1) -gt 0 ]; then gzip /tmp/filename.log; fi
```

Or simply:

```
[ $(du -s ./test.txt | cut -f1) -gt 0 ] && gzip /tmp/filename.log
```

In the last command, the command after `&&` will be run only if the previous command returns an exit status `0` i.e. success. So, you don't need an `if` condition after all.

Also if you are using `bash`, try to use the `bash` keyword `[[` instead of `test` `[` as it provides lots of features that `test` does not. So your command could take the following **final form**:

```
[[ $(du -s ./test.txt | cut -f1) -gt 0 ]] && gzip /tmp/filename.log
```

Or the **simplest way**:

```
[[ -s /tmp/filename.log ]] && gzip /tmp/filename.log
```

The `-s` indicates that if the file is greater than `0` in size then  will return true.

Comment: remove the `h` in `-sh`

Comment: `if [ $(du -s foo2 | awk '{print $1}') -gt 0 ]; then gzip foo2; fi`

Comment: @A.B.: `awk` is an overkill..

Comment: Hmpf, I like it. =)

Comment: With the if condition, if you are trying to check if the file is larger than 0 then you should be able to use the `-s` expression - there is a useful list [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)

Comment: @Wilf: Thanks..actually i was gonna put that at the end showing OP's mistakes gradually at first and what could made it easier at the end.. :)

Answer (score 4):

A good idea is to check his scripts with [this tool](http://www.shellcheck.net/).

Here is an annotated version of your error:

```
   1  #!/bin/bash
   2  sed -rne '/21:25:07/,/21:50:07/ p'  server.log.2015-04-21 > /tmp/filename.log ;
   3  du -sh  /tmp/filename.log ; 
   4  if [`du -sh  /tmp/filename.log` -gt 0] then gzip /tmp/filename.log ;
      ^––SC1009 The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
         ^––SC1073 Couldn't parse this test expression.
          ^––SC1035 You need a space after the [ and before the ].
                                            ^––SC1020 You need a space before the ].
                                            ^––SC1072 Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

[Source](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: Ooh...  I'm going to use this tool too from now on!

Answer (score -2):

```
if [ `du -sh  /tmp/filename.log` -gt 0 ]; then gzip /tmp/filename.log; fi
```

The spaces in if condition and fi at the end to close the if

Comment: `if [ $(du -s /tmp/filename.log | awk '{print $1}') -gt 0 ]; then gzip /tmp/filename.log; fi`

Comment: Or use `cut -f1` instead of awk. Replace the backticks with `$(..)` ;)